# Find all capturing groups of a regular expression

Tags: regex, haskell

I am looking for a Haskell function that returns the capturing groups of all matches of a given regex.

I have been looking at [Text.Regex](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/regex-compat/0.92/doc/html/Text-Regex.html), but couldn't find anything there.

Now I am using this workaround which seems to work:

```
import Text.Regex

findNext :: String -> Maybe (String, String, String, [String] ) -> [ [String] ]
findNext pattern Nothing = []
findNext pattern (Just (_, _, rest, matches) ) = 
    case matches of
        [] -> (findNext pattern res)
        _ -> [matches] ++ (findNext pattern res)
    where res = matchRegexAll (mkRegex pattern) rest

findAll :: String -> String -> [ [String] ]
findAll pattern str = findNext pattern (Just ("", "", str, [] ) )
```

Result:

```
findAll "x(.)x(.)" "aaaxAxaaaxBxaaaxCx"
[["A","a"],["B","a"]]
```

**Question:**

- Did I miss something in Text.Regex?
- Is there a Haskell regex library that implements a findAll function?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `=~` operator from [`Text.Regex.Posix`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/regex-posix/latest/doc/html/Text-Regex-Posix.html):

```
Prelude> :mod + Text.Regex.Posix
Prelude Text.Regex.Posix> "aaaxAxaaaxBxaaaxCx" =~ "x(.)x(.)" :: [[String]]
[["xAxa","A","a"],["xBxa","B","a"]]
```

Note the explicit `[[String]]` type. Try replacing it with `Bool`, `Int`, `String` and see what happens. All types that you can use in this context are listed [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/regex-base/0.93.2/doc/html/Text-Regex-Base-RegexLike.html#t:RegexContext). Also see [this tutorial](http://www.serpentine.com/blog/2007/02/27/a-haskell-regular-expression-tutorial/).

Comment: I didn't knew, that there was an interface different from `=~` to regices before...

Comment: @FUZxxl Nice pseudo plural of regex. I really laughed. regex, regicis, regici, regicem, o regex, regice... Is this common usage?

Comment: @Hyperboreus I derived it from index (indices), although it seems to be not the common plural which is regexes.

Comment: Of course, the correct plural of "regex" is, in fact, "regexen", as you can plainly derive by pluralizing "ox".

Comment: @Daniel Interesting point. ^^ Sure "index" is a latin word with genetive "indicis" and hence plural "indices". "Regex" is an acronym for "regular expression" and hence its plural is "regular expressions". ALthough, "regices" sounds way more sophisticated.

Comment: @Hyperboreus Arguably, since it is an acronym for "regular expression", the plural could be "regexs" (or "regexes", modelled after the word "ex").